# Using the substitution $y:=x/t$ determine the general solution of $\dot x=(t+x)/(t-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I get as  general solution an implicit equation so I dont know if I did this exercise correctly, can someone check it please? What I did was: if $y=x/t$ then $x=ty$ and consequently
$$
\dot x=y+t\dot y=\frac{1+y}{1-y}=\frac{t+x}{t-x}\implies t\dot y=\frac{1+y^2}{1-y}\implies\arctan y-\frac12\int\frac{2y\dot y}{1+y^2}=\ln|t|+C \\ \implies\arctan y=C+\ln\left|t\sqrt{1+y^2}\right|\implies x=t\tan\left(C+\ln\sqrt{t^2+x^2}\right)
$$

But the last expression seems that cannot be simplified further.

---

**UPDATE**: well, Wolfram Mathematica gives me the same implicit solution, so probably it cannot be simplified.

Comment: Shouldn't $dx/dt = \frac{1+ty}{1-ty}$?

Comment: @MathLover I had a typo in the title, now is right.